# Sprite position not updating to where it is being moved to

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, position, sknode, touchesmoved

Since I am working in spritekit, I decided not to use `UIScrollview` because from what I could tell it is difficult to implement. Instead, based on research online I decided to create an `SKNode` and add all of my sprites as children of the `SKNode`. From there, in the `touchesMoved` function, I moved my `SKNode` to replicate the `UIScrollview`. This part works perfect. The `SKNode` with all of the sprites moved wherever I scroll simulating the action, however, if I print out -> `print(spriteA.position)`, the value doesn't change from it's initial position. When i print out `print(SKNode.position)`, the value DOES change from it's initial position.

```
    blueBottle = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "Bottle"), size: CGSize(width: 0.065*size.height, height: 0.2*size.height))
    blueBottle.position = CGPoint(x: 0.8*size.width, y: topShelf.position.y + 0.5*topShelf.size.height + 0.5*blueBottle.size.height)
    blueBottle.name = "Play"
    blueBottle.zPosition = Layer.ui.rawValue
    moveableNode.addChild(blueBottle)

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            touchPoint = location
            secondLocation = location
        }
        moveableNode.position.y =  touchPoint.y - (firstLocation.y - moveableNodePos.y)
        print(moveableNode.position.y)
        print(bluebottle.position.y)
     }
```

This is pretty odd to me, as the sprite is successfully moving, however the position doesn't update... The only thing I can think of is that the sprite is not attached to the `SKNode` properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is working properly and the results are as expected.

position is the position within the parent. so in your case the sprites position within the SKNode which never changes.

Think of it this way if I asked you to pack a cooler, and said to pack Cokes on the left of the cooler and Coronas on the right. When we move that cooler to the camp ground the cokes still have the same position in the cooler. ;)

> Edit

further following with my same example

if I want to find out the Coke's position in relation to the campground and not the cooler I would have to convert it.

using...

`convert(_:to:)` or `convert(_:from:)`

From Apple...

Converting Between Coordinate Spaces
When working with the node tree, sometimes you need to convert a position from one coordinate space to another. For example, when specifying joints in the physics system, the joint positions are specified in scene coordinates. So, if you have those points in a local coordinate system, you need to convert them to the scene’s coordinate space.
The following code shows how to convert a node’s position into the scene coordinate system. The scene is asked to perform the conversion. Remember that a node’s position is specified in its parent’s coordinate system, so the code passes node.parent as the node to convert from. You could perform the same conversion in reverse by calling the `convert(_:to:)` method.

Comment: Oh, okay that makes a lot of sense! Is there any way to update the position?

Comment: The main goal is to be able to start an action when I click the sprite (touchesBegan) -> so if my sprite starts at the bottom of the screen and I move it up to the top, if i click it at the top it does nothing. If i click the empty space at the bottom where it originally was, the action will be called. Strange that it wouldn't recognize that the spriteA.frame.position is not there :(

Comment: I could theoretically write a line of code in the touchesMoved for every sprite that i want to move - it just seems like a lot of redundant code if i had - say 20+ sprites to move all at once.

Comment: Thank you so much! i figured it out and works perfectly now :) Very helpful Ron!